# Can openfire merge with mysql server

Tags: android, mysql, ldap, xmpp, openfire

I plan to create an application on android which use openfire(XMPP) and also use mysql to collect data at server.

My application need to:

```
1. Check login account
2. Send data to collect at server
3. Receive data from server
```

So,I need to know:

```
1. Could i download smack to my app right? how?
2. How openfire can work with mysql ?  
3. Should I use LDAP ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean by

> 1. Could i download smack to my app right? how?

Smack is just a series of JARs (i.e. a library). Are you asking where you can download Smack and how to integrate it into your application?

As for your MySQL related questions, I am currently working on a web-based Java application that uses Openfire. I have Openfire running its own MySQL database and my application also has its own MySQL database as its backend. When you ask how Openfire can work with MySQL, are you asking how you can set up Openfire so its own database is a MySQL database or how can Openfire extract users from another application that is running a MySQL database as its backend? Both can be done easily, please just clarify the question.

Comment: for smack, i want to know how to integrate to my app.

how can Openfire extract users from another application that is running a MySQL database as its backend seem to be my question. Actually, I have a web in another side which using app-serve, but i don't know if i use Openfire from android phone how can i connect with that database to get and send value.The value that keep in mysql must be use both on android phone and web. Do you have suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Firstly, to get Openfire to extract users is easy depending on how you store your passwords in the MySQL database it should be extracting from. If it is plain text then its simple, if it is encrypted (as it was in my case) then it becomes more complicated. There is quite a good post on setting this up [here](http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/194568#194568). This has a link to a guide that will help you through this. I suggest you start here and then if you run into any specific issues I should be able to assist

Comment: And secondly, regarding your Smack query: I have no Android experience but I integrated Smack into a GWT / Spring / Hibernate web-based Java application. I'm not sure how Android works but if your app is a Java app then you just use Smack as you would any other JARs. It is very easy to use, all you need to know can be found [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/)

Comment: Finally, When you say you are trying to connect to Openfire from an Android phone, do you mean that you have your Java app running on the phone and you want that to connect to Openfire or are you just trying to get the phone to connect to Openfire through a standard XMPP client application?

Comment: I think it's pretty much confuse in details, so I ask new question in another topic. Would you mind to answer me in the new topic ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483562/cannot-follow-external-databasemysql-of-openfire-server-quide : this is link of my new topic

Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

I know openfire can work with mysql, in my project, I have my own mysql db, when I setup openfire, write mysql db name as same as the openfire connection db name, so openfire can install itself's table into mysql db

and you also lookup this document

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html#mysql