# Cannot follow external database(MySQL) of openfire server quide

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire

1. I have MySQL database which I created on university's server
2. I try to develop android application that can send msg from mobile through XMPP protocol to keep data at my database server(from 1.)
3. At this time, I already downloaded openfire 3.7.0.dmg(MAC OS X) then try to setup server on my laptop

My problem is I cannot follow [Database Installation Guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html) the error occurred: Does not have mysqladmin command at my Terminal. So, I cannot create table for openfire. Should I need to install MySQL on my laptop ?

Moreover, I pretty much confuse with [YOUR_HOST] of this statement :

> jdbc:mysql://[YOUR_HOST]/[DATABASE_NAME]

I don't know what is it? should be localhost or anything?

Anyone can help me ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have MySQL installed on one computer you have access to.  If you want to install it on your Mac, you can either download it directly from [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), or you could install it using a package manager like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Next, make sure your MySQL install can listen for connections over TCP; there's a [troubleshooting guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) for that.

Next, use the name of the machine your MySQL server is running on in place of `[YOUR_HOST]`.  If it's running on the same machine as OpenFire, you can use `localhost`.

Comment: May I ask you, why I need to install MySQL in my computer,though I have MySQL database server that provided at my university? Apologize to disturb you. I'm very loss of knowledge about network. Thanks

Comment: If you've got a MySQL instance on another computer, use that computer's name for [YOUR_HOST].  In order to create the tables, you'll need the command line tools.  Those tools come with the database that you would install on your local box, or you can ssh to the remote box and use the tools that exist there.